# Why can one not draw a world in modal logic given necessity?

Tags: modal-logic, truth-tree

In [Modal Logic 1.2 -- truth trees for K about 1:30](https://youtu.be/fkS7cE8PA5I?t=89) into the video, the presenter said:

> If you have possibly *A* then you need to draw an arrow to a new world and derive *A* in that world because *w0* accesses some world in which *A* is the case.

Later he also said that the rule is different for necessity:

> The rule for necessity says that if you have an arrow to another world then you can use necessity to derive *A* in that world.

Basically, given possibility one can draw a world using a truth tree, but not with necessity. I think this has something to do with the accessibility of *w0* to this new world, *w1*, but I don't understand what that is or whether this rule is peculiar to system *K*.

Hence my question: *Why can one not draw a world in modal logic given necessity?*

Here is the [diagram completed as of about 3:30:](https://youtu.be/fkS7cE8PA5I?t=211)

[image]

For the first and fourth diagram the black circle about *w1* means that the world *w1* has to be there prior to deriving anything from necessity in that world. For the second and third diagram the red circle about *w1* means this world can be drawn and one can derive the possibility in that world.

---

Reference

Modal Logic 1.2 -- truth trees for system K, Kane B channel  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkS7cE8PA5I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Krippke's accessible worlds model:

If a statement is possible then there *exists* an accessible world where it happens to be true.  So if a thing is possible we can definitely find at least one accessible world where it happens.

If a statement is necessary then *for all* accessible worlds it happens to be so — which does not guarantee that there are in fact worlds accessible.  So if a thing is necessary then we may not be able to find any accessible worlds at all *but* it will definitely be true in any accessible world we might find.

Refer to the notion of vacuous truth.  If no worlds are accessible then everything is necessary.

Comment: I was beginning to suspect that was the reason.  Thank you for confirming it. I assume the additional axioms added to the various modal logics above K give one more accessible worlds. +1

Comment: @FrankHubeny Indeed. Frames with the axioms of Reflexivity (T: □p→p) or Seriality (D: □p→◊p) will guarantee an accessible world for any neccessary proposition.